# Qualifier in Spring JavaConfig

Tags: spring, inversion-of-control, spring-java-config

I'm trying to write one JavaConfig file, which will contain all dependencies to have the ability to choose injected class. 
For example one function of JavaConfig

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("bigWheel") // Has no impact (I have several types of wheel)
public Car getCar(Wheel wheel){
    return new Car(wheel);
}
```

Also when I mark Car class with @Component I got "No default constructor" exception. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You need a constructor without any argument.

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize that when Spring is creating your spring context and instantiating the beans it needs default constructors i.e. constructors without any parameters.  Quite simply it wouldn't know what Wheel to supply.

I also think you're likely to be unhappy using the pseudo-reserved get/set methods as an object name.  Regardless of your Qualifier annotation you are creating an object getCar of class Car.

It kinda looks like you are trying to make getCar a factory method?  I'm not going to write a big description in case that's not what you're doing.  But if so your pattern needs some work.

EDIT:  From your comment below I really don't think you want a bean instantiated at context creation time.  It sounds like you just want a regular Spring Aware bean that can use Cars and Wheels.  Something like This.

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class Wheel {
... wheel stuff
}

@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
class Car {
   ... car stuff
}

@Component
class Dealership extends ApplicationContextAware {

 @Autowired 
 ApplicationContext applicationContext;

 ... bunch of dealership code

 Wheel wheel = (Wheel) applicationContext.getBean("Wheel");
 Car   car   = (Car)   applicationContext.getBean("Car");
 car.setWheel(wheel);
 ... profit
```

It just doesn't sound like you are looking for a global singleton called wheel that is injected into the global singleton car, during context initialization.

That is why I added the SCOPE_PROTOTYPE annotations above.  Normally Spring will instantiate an object and keep injeting that object when you call for it.  This works well most of the time.  But if your object starts storing state or if you're multithreaded of course, that doesn't work.

But Spring can't figure that out.  So if you want a unique object instantiated for each getBean call, you have to add the @Scope annotation.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, now I get that spring will "create an object getCar of class Car", I renamed it.

All I want to do - to make me able to choose wheel type outside of Car class. Currently I know how to choose Wheel class inside Car class (with Qualifier annotation). But it has not much sense as for me.